# Usage of xRandR with 3D applications

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have problem on Ubuntu 18.04 using 1080p TV and xRandR to replicate 1440p virtual super resolution since 3D apps can't use it. 3D apps can't see xRandR's resolution which results in 1/4 filled display and the rest is filled with graphical glitches.

#### Solutions tried

1. **Adding new mode to xRandR**

   I tried to add new mode with 2560x1440_60.00 resolution using `$ gtf 2560 1440 60` to get parameters and then i executed

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync
   xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 2560x1440_60.00
   ```

   This resulted in a black screen.
2. **Temporary solution (not ideal)**

   I'm able to modify some 3D application's config to force them to use this resolution, but some if them will "refresh" its config with the default resolution nor won't use.

   I'm forced run the following command to make it work on fullscreen without glitches.

   ```
    xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --fb 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --rate 60
   ```

Comment: There's no need to use ALL CAPS and headers together. The header lines are large enough.

Comment: Noted.. I wanted to make it easier to read.